# Reverse an Array in place using Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

The task is to reverse an array in place using assembly. The problem I'm currently having with my method is that edi which is intended to have the memory address of the last element in the array before entering the loop is not correct.  What am I missing here? Thanks in advance! (This is not a school assignment I am working out of a textbook but I'm relearning assembly so that I can become a better reverse engineer)

```
; reverse an array in place

.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD

.data
myArray DWORD 12h, 34h, 56h, 78h
arrSize DWORD ?

.code
main PROC
    mov arrSize, SIZEOF myArray
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF myArray/2
    mov esi, OFFSET myArray
    mov edi, esi
    add edi, arrSize
    L1:
        ;move the first element into register to swap with last element
        mov al, [esi]
        ;move last element into register to swap with first element
        mov bl, [edi]
        ;move value in eax to last element in array
        movzx edi, al
        mov esi, bl
        ;inc esi
        ;dec edi
    loop L1
    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: As you have set it up `edi` points past the last item since you added the size of the array. Also your array is dwords but your code loads bytes and it doesn't even write the values out. `mov esi, bl` should not even assemble.

Comment: To update an array you have to have some kind of storing instruction — you don't have any `mov` that update/stores to memory, so you're just reading the array.

Comment: @Jester you are correct in that the line **bold** `mov esi, bl` doesn't assemble I uncommented that code and haven't even reached that point in the execution.  Here is where I think the problem is but I'm unsure how to fix it.

Line 23: **bold** `mov bl, [edi]` should load the value 78h into bl but it doesn't instead I get 005DA010 in the eax register.  If you compare that to Line 21 **bold** `mov al, [esi]` I get the value 0075FE12 in EAX.  It seems like I am not correctly calculating the memory address stored in edi before the loop.

Comment: As I said, you set `edi` past the array. You need to subtract 4 if you use dwords, or 1 if you use bytes.

Comment: @Jester you are a wizard.  That did work for me I'm going to go review my Data Sizes. Thank you very much.

Comment: To load bytes, you usually want `movzx eax, byte ptr [esi]`, but to store you want `mov [edi], al`.  (A zero-extending load isn't necessary for correctness, but it's usually more efficient than making the CPU merge the byte with the previous value of the rest of the register. If you're looking at the register in a debugger, only the low byte is relevant anyway.)  `movzx edi, al` overwrites the pointer with the data you're supposed to be swapping; that makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks Peter that is helpful. I figured out that I was overwriting my pointer. I appreciate your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with:

```
.code
main PROC
    mov arrSize, SIZEOF myArray - 4 ;the difference between the starting address and the ending address
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF myArray/2 ;length of the array cut in half
    mov esi, OFFSET myArray ;the beginning address of the array
    mov edi, OFFSET myArray + SIZEOF myArray - TYPE myArray
    L1:
        mov eax, [esi] ;move the first element into register to swap with last element
        mov ebx, [edi] ;move last element into register to swap with first element
        mov [edi], eax ;move value in eax to last element in array
        mov [esi], ebx
        add esi, TYPE myArray
        sub edi, TYPE myArray
    loop L1
    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main
```